# Cannot find OptimisticConcurrencyException in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am migrating my application from EF6 to EF Core, In the EF6 we have "OptimisticConcurrencyException", "EntitySqlException", "DbEntityValidationException" and "EntityCommandExecutionException" exception types, however, I cannot find their equivalent exceptions in the EF Core. are there any in the EF Core ? or there is no usage of these exceptions in the EF Core?

Comment: Even in EF 6 the [correct exception is DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/concurrency)